# Joules do not makes sense to me

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

This is a fairly basic question that I am extremely confused about. I have a pretty bad physics teacher that cannot answer this question and is not even willing to, so here I am.

The definition of a joule is the amount of energy required to move 1 newton of mass 1 meter, and time is not a factor of a joule. Now, suppose there are two bodies of mass, $A$ and $B$, on a collision course, where $A$ is more massive than $B$, and suppose friction is negligible. They are both pushed at the same force, 100 newtons, and for the same time, but because $A$ is more massive than $B$, $A$ will receive the force during a smaller distance, let's arbitrarily choose 10 meters for this example. $B$, because it is lighter, will have the force exerted during 50 meters for this example. Does that mean that $B$ will have more energy in joules than $A$? Doesn't physics tell us their collision has the same kinetic energy?

This might be a pretty obvious question to some, but it genuinely confuses me. Am I getting something wrong or is there some underlying truth to physics that I have not gotten to yet? I am just starting out physics currently.

Comment: "The definition of a joule is the amount of energy required to move 1 kg of mass 1 meter": it is not. A joule is the work done by a force of one newton acting over one meter.

Comment: I taught high school physics for 13 years.  In my opinion, you have some ingrained concepts that are incorrect, and some of those concepts may well have come from "Hollywood physics".  As difficult as it will be, you need to open your mind, do your best to identify the incorrect concepts that you have internalized, and do your best to jettison those incorrect concepts.  And note that some of the answers will come when you study the work-energy theorem, so be patient.

Comment: Why is this question closed? It seems to adress a clear confusion regarding the concept of energy.

Comment: "to move 1 newton of mass 1 meter". Mass is not measured in newtons: force is. Actually, the mass of the object is irrelevant. See rob's definition above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1)** $B$ will have higher kinetic energy yes. Concretely if the mass of $A$ is double as that of $B$, with the same force, using Newton 2nd law, both cases will play as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
F= m_B\ a_B \equiv m\ a_B \\
F=m_A \ a_A = 2m\ a_B
\end{cases} \longrightarrow  a_A= \frac12a_B \ \text{ or in other words } \  a_B=2\ a_A
\end{equation} where $a_i$ is the acceleration $A$ or $B$ will receive. Then because they receive this acceleration the same amount of time ($\Delta t$), and because $a=\Delta v / \Delta t$, the velocity on $A$ will be half the velocity of $B$ ($v_B=2v_A$).

And the kinetic energy is $K=\frac12 m v^2$, which means that the kinetic energy for both objects will be:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
K_B=\frac12 m_B v_B^2 \equiv  \frac12 m v^2\\
K_A=\frac12 m_A v_A^2= \frac12 2m (\frac v2)^2 = (\frac24)   \frac12 m v^2
\end{cases} \longrightarrow  K_A=\frac12K_B \ \text{ or in other words } \  K_B=2\ K_A
\end{equation}
you see? It would be nice if you generalize this for any ratio between the masses $m_A/m_B\equiv r$ as an excercice which will make you see the pattern!

---

---

**Question 2)** What does the sentence "Doesn't physics tell us their collision has the same kinetic energy" mean? I think you wrote that wrongly, but I'll try to prevent any confusion:

The amount of energy they gain by this external force is prior to any collision, so the collision can't limit at all the energy they will gain from it, only the things that happen from the collision on!